# What Type is Needed When Typescript Function Returns Method on Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have function which returns method on parameter and typescript says Error that my parameter has any type and I have tried using Function type but it still says error so which type is assignable to a something like this function? `const PreventParentOnClick = (event) => event.stopPropagation()`

```
(event: what should I type here ? )
```

Comment: On what event is the function called?

Comment: @lpizzinidev it's called on onClick event.

Comment: use `MouseEvent`

Comment: When i added MouseEvent that error disappeared but another one appeared where i pass that function in onClick={PreventParentOnClick}  and it says: No overload matches this call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the event should be `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`.
Also, make sure that your function starts with a lowercase letter:

```
const preventParentOnClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => { 
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the entire function as what it is, a `MouseEventHandler`. `event` will be inferred to be a `MouseEvent`.

```
const preventParentOnClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement> = (event) => { 
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```